# jq double backslash sometime removed

Tags: json, string, jq, backslash

I have a first json file like this:

```
{
  "env_vars": {
    "TERRAFORM_CFG_TLS_CERT": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----\\nMIIIqzCCB5O"
  }
}
```

If I use the command:

```
echo <file> | jq -r '.env_vars'
```

The result is as expected (the backslash are still there):

```
{
  "TERRAFORM_CFG_TLS_CERT": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----\\nMIIIqzCCB5O"
}
```

But if i execute this command:

```
cat <file> | jq -r '.env_vars' | jq -r 'keys[] as $k | "\($k)=\"\(.[$k])\""'
```

The result is:

```
TERRAFORM_CFG_TLS_CERT: "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----\nMIIIqzCCB5O"
```

=> One backslash has been removed... why ?
How to avoid this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using the -r option tells jq to "translate" the JSON string into a "raw" string by interpreting the characters that are special to JSON (see e.g. http://json.org).  Thus, following the [[mcve]](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guidelines a bit more closely, we could start with:

```
$ jq . <<< '"X\\nY"'
"X\\nY"

$ jq -r . <<< '"X\\nY"'
X\nY
```

If you check the json.org specification of strings, you'll see this is exactly correct.

So if for some reason you want each occurrence of  `\\` in the JSON string to be replaced by two backslash characters (i.e. JSON: `"\\\\"`), you could use `sub` or `gsub`.  That's a bit tricky, because the first argument of these functions is a regex.  Behold:

```
$ jq -r 'gsub("\\\\"; "\\\\")' <<< '"X\\nY"'
X\\nY
```

Answer (score 0):

You should output the string as json to preserve the escapes. By taking a string and outputting it raw, you're getting exactly what that string was, a literal backslash followed by an `n`.

```
$ ... | jq -r '.env_vars | to_entries[] | "\(.key): \(.value | tojson)"'
```

If any of the values are non-strings, add a `tostring` to the filter.